# asp net texbox text style in middle

Tags: css, asp.net, .net, padding

i have this textbox that I have customized with CSS, for some reason, if you type lots of text, it breaks in the middle, meaning it doesnt use the entire "window" what is the problem?

ASPX:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

CSS:

```
#txtNotes {
    z-index: 999999;
    padding: 5px 240px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: well? is there anybody out there?

Comment: I wrote an answer, but It just occurred to me, that you might be using padding because you wanted that size on the input? In that case, please use width instead of padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your current css rules is set to have 240px padding to the right, inside the input field. Which means that the field must always have 240px of space between the text and the right border of the input field. This will prevent your text from using the entire width of the input.

May I suggest removing the extra padding to the right?

Please also keep in mind that padding-left and padding-bottom are not necessary.
This css rule would replace them but give the same result:

```
padding: 5px 240px 30px 5px;
```

The order goes: Top - Right - Bottom - Left

Please try replacing your css rule with the following:

CSS:

```
#txtNotes {
    z-index: 999999;
    padding: 5px 5px 30px 5px;
}
```

Comment: It depends allot on what you actually expect to happen. If the issue is with you wanting the text to use more then one row, then I would suggest you change the input to a textarea instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#txtNotes {
        z-index: 999999;
        padding: 5px 5px 30px 5px;

    }
```

Comment: Then how come you accepted the answer above? That is same as mine.

Answer (score 0):

I looks to me you want a `<textarea>` and not a TextBox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ClientIDMode="Static" />

<style>
    #txtNotes {
        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
    }
</style>
```